# Undefined class constant 'TYPE_SHIPPING'

Tags: magento-enterprise

I am getting below error, any help would be appreciated on making this error go away.
 `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'TYPE_SHIPPING' in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php on line 535` `

> Call Stack: 0.0003 662728 1. {main}() /index.php:0 0.0021 1220368 2.
>   Mage::run() /index.php:86 0.0070 3067968 3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
>   /app/Mage.php:683 2.3175 20496024 4.
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354 2.3263 22448616 5.
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176 2.3283
>   23055408 6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250
>   2.4710 29822912 7. Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction() /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:419 2.4714
>   29913656 8. Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php:45 2.4715
>   29913656 9. Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php:52 2.7074 43451768 10.
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php:137 2.7076 43453432 11.
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:390 2.7076
>   43453568 12. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555 2.7079 43458392 13.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863 2.7079 43458392 14.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286 2.7084 43459440 15.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272 2.7087 43521872 16.
>   include('/app/design/frontend/anatomical/default/template/page/1column.phtml')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241 2.7582 44914856 17.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml()
>   /app/design/frontend/anatomical/default/template/page/1column.phtml:11
>   2.7582 44915016 18. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml() /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:526 2.7582 44915016 19.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:582 2.7585 44915384 20.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863 2.7585 44915384 21.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286 2.7587 44915576 22.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272 2.7589 44987520 23.
>   include('/app/design/frontend/anatomical/default/template/page/html/header.phtml')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241 2.7589 44987664 24.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml()
>   /app/design/frontend/anatomical/default/template/page/html/header.phtml:13
>   2.7589 44987824 25. Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml() /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:526 2.7589 44987824 26.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:582 2.7590 44988184 27.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863 2.7590 44988184 28.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286 2.7592 44988384 29.
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272 2.7594 45092488 30.
>   include('/app/design/frontend/anatomical/default/template/checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241 2.7629 46209000 31.
>   Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getSubtotal()
>   /app/design/frontend/anatomical/default/template/checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml:38
>   2.7629 46209160 32. Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Abstract->getTotals() /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php:114 2.7629
>   46209160 33. Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getTotalsCache()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Abstract.php:179 2.7629
>   46209520 34. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getTotals()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php:257 2.7662
>   47298600 35. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->getShippingAddress()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:1267

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the case for you, but I've seen this on a website after an upgrade.
The constants are actually defined in `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract` but only in newer versions.
In my case, the previous dev, copied the `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract` class to the `local` folder (for some changes), and after the upgrade, that class was still used and it did not contain the constants `TYPE_BILLING` and `TYPE_SHIPPING`.

What I'm trying to say is investigate the `local` folder for things that might affect the addresses.

Comment: That was the case for me, too!