# checkout error Undefined class constant 'CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY'

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am having a rather serious problem with my magento installation.

when trying to put through a  test order i note that suddenly my checkout is no longer working
 i get the error

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY' in
>   /public_html/includes/src/Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container.php on
>   line 65

I have not actually done any changes to that file.

can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

include/src/ is where magento places the 'compiled' classes.
Do you have (or want) compilation mode to be enabled?

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

Did you maybe install something, or recently clear the cache?
Disable compilation, clear cache, then re-enable

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
```

Check outcome:

```
 php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
```

Now clear your cache, and re-enable compilation if you want to use it again. (but it could be possible that something got installed that does not work with compilation - which is an entire new question ;) )

Comment: i have done all that and uninstalled what i had recently installed- a couple of modules that should not have anything to do with that class.
Same thing.
 My hosting support says this might have something to do with the last magento update but i think that's bollox. The last update was in november, surely it would have acted before now

Comment: now it's Undefined class constant 'CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY' in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php on line 65

Comment: i have even restored the file to how it was on 2/2/15 with no success :(

Comment: Have you disabled compilation, and leave it off? - so disable, clear cache.

Comment: I have, no joy.

Comment: can you give the result of php -f shell/compiler.php -- state

Comment: Also have a look in your app/code/local folder for any magento classes that may have been copied into the local namespace. ref: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29361/undefined-class-constant-type-shipping

Comment: in local there is one file only in the local/mage/payment/method/abstract.php and it does not contain the class

Comment: will post the result of teh compiler when i get home. thank you so much for your help

Comment: The error should be in that file (local/mage/payment/method/abstract.php)

Answer (score 0):

The constant `CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY` that is referred to is defined in the following class:

`Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`

If the constant is not defined, it means that there must be something wrong in that specific class.